# Can we have a custom close reason for graphic design questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

It has [previously been agreed](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-do-we-draw-the-line-between-questions-that-are-appropriate-for-computer-grap) that questions from a designer point of view, about using graphics software to achieve a desired style, are not suitable for our site.

We still seem to get one of these questions every couple of days, and when we do, I usually vote-to-close with a custom off-topic reason, along the lines of:

> [I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because] it is about graphic design/using graphics software, not computer graphics techniques or research.

It fits into the format but it's not ideal. Since this is a recurring pattern, would it be useful to put some better wording into one of our slots for site-specific off-topic reasons?

---

I'm hanging out in chat if anyone wants to work together to draft the text for this.

Comment: I agree that it might be a good idea to create a custom off-topic reason for such questions. As for the specific text, I'd like the custom reasons to be constructive, so ideally telling what can be improved or (in this case) where to ask instead, in addition to the reasoning why the question is off-topic. And if we point at some other site we should make sure that the off-topic close reason matches the topic of the other site. We should be able to find some examples at other sites of the network which already have similar things.

Comment: Are there more frequently occurring situations that should get custom close options? When I [asked about a custom close option in GDSE](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2261/33287) I was informed SEs generally get 3 custom close reasons (& very rarely a 4th). Is this situation deserving enough?

Comment: @Pikalek I can't think of one. Even if we use one for this situation, it can be swapped out later if another problem becomes more common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my first draft:-

> Questions about **creating artwork** or **using** graphics software **as an end-user** are off-topic for this site. Consider if your question might be re-written to fit on [Graphic Design](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If your question is about Blender, it might fit on [Blender](//blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Since nobody had any edits or alternatives, I went ahead and added this one.