# Hardware Questions are off-topic on Blender SE, too

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Yesterday, [this question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/5729/7431) was closed as off-topic since it was about hardware compatibility. This is great, but I disagree with the close reason:

> "Questions about creating artwork or using graphics software as an end-user are off-topic for this site. Consider if your question might be re-written to fit on Graphic Design. If your question is about Blender, it might fit on Blender."

Blender SE *also* does not like questions about hardware compatibility, see [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/26640).

I don't think that it is a good idea to direct users with off-topic questions to a site where that question will still be off-topic.

Comment: What would you suggest instead? Should we not mention Blender at all? There's a reason the links (which you omitted from your copy) point to help/on-topic for the sites instead of /ask or the front page.

Comment: Discussion (such as it is) for this custom close reason was on [this question](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/can-we-have-a-custom-close-reason-for-graphic-design-questions) so you should propose an alternative there.

Comment: @DanHulme Just to clarify, is the cited off-topic reason the only off-topic closure reason available here?

Comment: @Pikalek There's that and the standard "off-site resource" one. Arguably this particular question is as good a match with either. Maybe I should have written a better explanation, but I just picked the one that seemed most appropriate. As a matter of interest, most of the reason for mentioning Blender.SE is that there was a spate of "how do I *x* in Blender" questions right before I drafted the text, but I don't think we've had any since then, so I for one would have no objection to just removing that sentence.

Comment: @DanHulme The close reason itself is good, and I think that it is worded fine. I just wanted to clarify when it should be used. The question had nothing to do with `creating artwork or using graphics software`, but was only asking about hardware compatibility, so I think that `Blatantly off topic` would have been a better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, following the discussion I'm just going to say *mea culpa*. I was a little lazy and chose the easiest thing to do to get rid of a question that could not be made on-topic through edits. It seemed expedient and unproblematic at the time, but I should have considered the risk of pointing the questioner at other sites where the question would be equally off-topic. My mistake caused work for other people.

I'll try to be more careful in future when wielding my mod hammer.